# Hello, I would like to filter my searched record in list view in vb.net. I am still beginner in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

When I search for the record in the list view, it highlights the searched record but does not filter only the required record. I want only the search records to be displayed in the list. please help me. my list view name is lvRoom, the textbox name is txtsearch and the button name is btnfind

This is my code.

```
Private Sub btnfind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnfind.Click

        Dim searchrecord As String = txtsearch.Text
        lvRoom.SelectedIndices.Clear()

        For Each lvr As ListViewItem In lvRoom.Items

            For Each lvrsub As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In lvr.SubItems

                If lvrsub.Text = searchrecord Then

                    lvRoom.SelectedIndices.Add(lvr.Index)

                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
        lvRoom.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of a ListView, you can use a DataGridView, set its DataSource to a BindingSource, the DataSource of the latter to your source of data. After that, you can use the `Filter` property of the BindingSource to filte the data -- Filters are usually applied to specific Columns, using specific data types -- If you need to keep the ListView, then you may want to filter the data that created the ListView's Items, generate a subset of the data and rebuild the ListView with the new data. Or find a bindable ListView Control (a ListView that provides a `DataSource` property)

Comment: What values do you have in your list and what are you searching for?

Comment: The values are Room number, Room Type, Room Rate.  Displayed from Ms access database onto a list veiw